# Create an automatically-incremented database field in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, auto-increment

I have a `Game` class, each Game has many `Round` instances (One-To-Many). Both classes have an automatically incremented `id` field as their primary key.

I would like `Round` to have another field named `ordinal`, that whenever I create a new `Round` object associated with a single `Game`, the `ordinal` field would be automatically filled with the next ordinal **for that specific game**.

**Example:**

- The Game object: `Game(id=71)`
- The first Round object of that game: `Round(id=389, game_id=71, ordinal=0)`
- Now creating a new Round object for the game, it will be the second one, indicated by the value of the `ordinal` field: `Round(id=514, game_id=71, ordinal=1)`

Class `Round` has the following line in the definition (though I'm not 100% that this is the right way to go):

```
`@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ordinal", "game_id"}))`
```

I could query for all `Round` objects of that specific game, see what's the `ordinal` of the last one, and manually set the new `ordinal` to be one more than that. But I was wondering if there is some built-in mechanism that does that for me. Hopefully with some annotation (like `@UniqueConstraint`).

I am using Java 7, Hibernate (JPA 2), and MySQL and H2 databases.

Answer (score 0):

There is a annotation @OrderColumn(name = "ordinal") that you can use. Add it to the  Round collection. It defines the name of a column in the table, containing the index in the list.